# Entity Framework on Winforms

Tags: winforms, entity-framework, ef-code-first, localdb

Windows 7 64bit, VS 2012, SQL 2012 localdb, EF 5.0, .net 4.5

I'm developing a new Winforms app using EF code first.  I've been following Julie Lermans books and examples for EF, Code First and Dbcontext.  Her examples use console applications and I have no trouble getting them to work and create my db.  However, when I replace the console app with a forms app using identical code the db is not getting created.  The only differenece is that I'm putting the console app Sub Main code in the Form1 load event.  With everything else identical I don't see why it isn't working.  It must have something to do with the start up sequence in console apps versus forms apps but I can't figure out what to do to make it work.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm having the same problem with WPF. If you figured this out, please let me know.